# lighttpd How to allow executing fcgi programs on www folder?

Tags: lighttpd, fcgi

This is the first time I install lighttpd and I'm having a hard time configuring fcgi to work on */var/www/site/*

I keep getting 403 Forbidden and so far have only found guides specific to php or that use workarounds.

**What is the proper way to get fastcgi working on another folder?**

My configuration files:

`lighttpd.conf`

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
    #"mod_rewrite",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

and `10-fastcgi.conf`

`server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )`

Fast CGI was successfully enabled and the server restarted, I tried many suggestions I found but none of them worked, they usually crashed the server.

Please pardon my ignorance and point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the [lightty fastcgi docs](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI) at all? It looks you need to be specifying a `fastcgi.server` option to lighttpd and giving info such as `ip` and `port`, and extensions to map to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `php` and `php-cgi` are installed, and then add the following to your `lighttpd.conf`

```
fastcgi.server = ( 
    ".php" => (( "bin-path"  => "/usr/bin/php-cgi", 
                                "socket"                => "/var/run/lighttpd/php.socket",
                                "max-procs"             => 2,                    
                                "bin-environment"       => ( "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN"     => "10",
                                                             "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000" ),
                                "bin-copy-environment"  => ( "PATH", "SHELL", "USER" ),
                                "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable" ))           
)
```

After you add the following, restart lighttpd and it should work. You can increase the processes and threads according to your server resources.